# Global rate limiter for nodejs bee-queue using redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a node app receiving requests to admit records to another application. I'm trying to solve a problem wherein the target application can only handle 1 request / 50ms, while the node app often receives requests every 30ms. I tried implementing [this example](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue/issues/148) using bee-queue and redis so all queues use a shared global concurrency limit. Rapid requests (40ms apart) should be processed one every 5 seconds in the test case below, but it still behaves as if the two threads operate in isolation and processes everything without any delays.

Output:

```
// app launched, messages received back-to-back
node-app_1      | 2021-01-14T18:27:29: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
node-app_1      | 2021-01-14T18:27:29: PM2 log: App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
node-app_1      | 2021-01-14T18:27:29: PM2 log: App [app:0] online
node-app_1      | tcp interface listening on 8888
node-app_1      | Message Event: A04 (timestamp: 1610668454624)
node-app_1      | ************sending ack****************
node-app_1      | Message Event: A04 (timestamp: 1610668454653)
node-app_1      | ************sending ack****************

// message one queued, processed
node-app_1      | 901999 job published to queue
node-app_1      | 901999 limiter available, consuming job
node-app_1      | 901999 admission job triggered

// message two queued, processed
node-app_1      | 901028 job published to queue
node-app_1      | 901028 limiter available, consuming job
node-app_1      | 901028 admission job triggered


// jobs complete, records created
node-app_1      | 901999 creating new record: 205
node-app_1      | 901028 creating new record: 205
```

If successful, it will admit the first as 205 and the second as 206. The limiter should delay the second admission request ("901028 limiter available, triggering admission") until after the first is admitted ("901028 creating new record").

Here's the line that queues the job:

```
const { queueJob } = require('../redcap_queue');
...
queueJob(data)
    .then(() => console.log( `${data.visit_number} job published to queue` ))
    .catch(() => console.log( "Record could not be admitted" ));
```

The queue handler:

```
const Queue = require('bee-queue');
var redcapAPI = require('./redcapAPI.js');
var limiter = require('./bottleneck');

const options = {
    removeOnSuccess: true,
    redis: {
        host: <redis_ip>,
        port: 6379,
    },
}

const redcapQueue = new Queue('redcap', options);

// Publisher
const queueJob = (data) => {
    return redcapQueue.createJob(data).save();
};

// Consumer
redcapQueue.on('ready', async () => {
    // wait for limiter
    await limiter.limiter.schedule(async () => {
        console.log(`${job.data.visit_number} limiter available, consuming job`);
        // process job
        redcapQueue.process(async job => {
            redcapAPI.importNewRecord(job.data);
            console.log(`${job.data.visit_number} admission job triggered`);
            done();
        })
    })
})

module.exports.queueJob = queueJob;
```

Here's my implementation of bottleneck (adapted from the example above)

```
var Bottleneck = require("bottleneck");

const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  id: 'my_global_limiter',
  datastore: 'redis',
  clearDatastore: false,
  clientOptions: {
    host: <redis_ip>,
    port: 6379,
  },
  maxConcurrent: 1,
  mintime: 5000
});

module.exports.limiter = limiter;
```